# REST API request using Hibernate relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

Rest Controller:

```
@PostMapping("transaction")
public ResponseEntity<Transaction> init(@RequestBody Transaction transactionInput) {
    Transaction transaction = transactionRepository.save(transactionInput);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(transaction, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Transaction Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="currency_id")
    private Currency currency;
```

Currency Entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "currency")
public class Currency {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Length(max = 3)
    private String sign;

    @Length(max = 30)
    private String name;
```

Request:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/transaction-service/transaction \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "currency_id": 1
}'
```

And it obviously currency is null and I got this error:

> could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [currency_id];
>   nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement

Is there a way to automatically mapping when I sending request with

```
"currency" = {"name" = "USD"}
```

Or how should I send this request?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert `Transaction` before `Currency` is inserted. The way you do it, it seems you are trying to insert a Transaction with its `optional=false` column `currency_id` set to `null`.

If you store the `Currency` entity first, then it should work. I am not sure if there is any good way to make such a "cascade insert" thing.

Also, this is not a good `@OneToOne` entity design - there is no constraint that ensures it is really one to one. CurrencyId should either be a primary key or have some unique constraint to ensure it is one to one. There is no apparent meaning of Transaction class from the snippet you posted, either.

Comment: I store the Currency entity first, I don't need to insert a currency record when I insert transaction. But it doesn't work. Could you please clarify why it's not good design? I did it as in manual about OneToOne unidirectional

Comment: Ok, I understood my mistake. It should be ManyToOne relation. Anyway, thanks for the answer @Vlasec

Comment: Yeah, `@ManyToOne` fits better, definitely. I guess making multiple transactions in a single currency is quite expected. As for `@OneToOne`, I think I explained myself quite well, but it doesn't fit this scenario. You can't ensure it being 1:1 unless you create a *unique constraint* on the *foreign key* (which would be `Transaction.currency` in this poorly fitting example). The closest connection is when this *foreign key* is also a *primary key* - it is *the cleanest 1:1 solution*, but in some solutions with a common unique sequence for all objects in DB, it is impossible to do.